# Creating nested hash in ruby or use of group_by

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array as follows:

```
my_array = [
  [1426049999000, "Apple", 2.7235],
  [1426049999000, "Orange", 2.942],
  [1424235599000, "Apple", 1.124],
  [1424235599000, "Orange", 1.115]
]
```

I want either a hash of hashes:

```
{
  :"Apple" => {1426049999000 => 2.7235, 1424235599000 => 1.124},
  :"Orange" => {1426049999000 => 2.942, 1424235599000 => 1.115}
}
```

or a hash of arrays:

```
{
  :"Apple" => [[1426049999000, 2.7235], [1424235599000, 1.124]],
  :"Orange" => [[1426049999000, 2.942], [1424235599000, 1.115]]
}
```

How can I create a nested hash or a hash of arrays that I want?

I tried:

```
my_array.group_by { |s| s[1] }
```

Output received:

```
{
  :"Apple" => [[1426049999000, "Apple", 2.7235], [1424235599000, "Apple", 1.124]],
  :"Orange" => [[1426049999000, "Orange", 2.942], [1424235599000, "Orange", 1.115]]
}
```

Comment: `:1426049999000` is not a valid symbol. Did you mean `:"Apple"`, `"Apple"` or `:Apple`?

Comment: Sorry I think it should be "1426049999000". I will update the question. Thanks!

Comment: see `"Apple" ` and `:Apple` makes sense... not `:"Apple" `.. It will sense when you have `:"Apple red" ` etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do :

```
my_array = [[1426049999000, "Apple", 2.7235], [1426049999000, "Orange", 2.942], [1424235599000, "Apple", 1.124], [1424235599000, "Orange", 1.115]]
my_array.each_with_object({}) { |a, h| (h[a[1]] ||= []) << a.values_at(0, 2) }
# => {"Apple"=>[[1426049999000, 2.7235], [1424235599000, 1.124]], "Orange"=>[[1426049999000, 2.942], [1424235599000, 1.115]]}
my_array.each_with_object({}) { |a, h| (h[a[1]] ||= {}).update(a[0] => a[2]) }
# => {"Apple"=>{1426049999000=>2.7235, 1424235599000=>1.124}, "Orange"=>{1426049999000=>2.942, 1424235599000=>1.115}}
```

Answer (score 1):

My friend @Arup has pointed out that my latter (original) expression did not return the result requested by the OP. That is true, but it would have been more accurate to say that, since I offered two ways of returning the same result (a hash whose values were arrays of hashes), neither expression returned the requested result.

In any event, I modified my original answer to conform to the OP's instructions, and wish to thank Arup for his eagle-eye.

```
my_array = [[1426, "Apple",  2.723],
            [1426, "Orange", 2.942],
            [1424, "Apple",  1.124],
            [1424, "Orange", 1.115]]
```

**Expression #1**

To produce a hash with values that are hashes:

```
my_array.each_with_object({}) { |(v1,fruit,v2),h|
  h.update(fruit.to_sym => {v1=>v2}) { |_,ov,nv| ov.update(nv) } }
  #=> {:Apple=>{1426=>2.723,  1424=>1.124},
  #    :Orange=>{1426=>2.942, 1424=>1.115}}
```

or with values that are arrays of arrays:

```
my_array.each_with_object({}) { |(v1,fruit,v2),h|
  h.update(fruit.to_sym => [[v1, v2]]) { |_,ov,nv| ov+nv } }
  #=> {:Apple=> [[1426, 2.723], [1424, 1.124]],
   #   :Orange=>[[1426, 2.942], [1424, 1.115]]}
```

I would suggest the latter, in the event that `[1424, "Apple", 1.124]` in  `my_array` were instead, say, `[1426, "Apple",  1.124]`, there would not be a problem of `1426` being a duplicate key.

**Expression #2**

```
my_array.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) { |(v1,fruit,v2),h|
  h[fruit.to_sym] << [v1,v2] }
  #=> {:Apple=> [[1426, 2.723], [1424, 1.124]],
  #    :Orange=>[[1426, 2.942], [1424, 1.115]]}
```

Comment: Your Last answer output not matching with the output of OP :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
groups =  { :"Apple" => [[1426049999000, "Apple", 2.7235], [1424235599000, "Apple", 1.124]],
      :"Orange" => [[1426049999000, "Orange", 2.942], [1424235599000, "Orange", 1.115]]}

groups.each{|k,v| v.each{|ar| ar.delete(k.to_s)}}
p groups # => {:Apple=>[[1426049999000, 2.7235], [1424235599000, 1.124]], :Orange=>[[1426049999000, 2.942], [1424235599000, 1.115]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p my_array.group_by{|x| x.delete_at(1)} #=> {"Apple"=>[[1426049999000, 2.7235], [1424235599000, 1.124]], "Orange"=>[[1426049999000, 2.942], [1424235599000, 1.115]]}


# or my_array.map(&:rotate).group_by(&:shift)
```